# Checking if $f_n$ or $\sum f_n$converges uniformly

Tags: real-analysis

> (i) $f_n = n^2 x \space e^{-nx^2}$. Does $f_n$ converge uniformly on $[0,1]$ ?
>
> (ii) $f_n = (1-x^2)^2 x^n $. Prove that $\sum f_n$ converge uniformly on $
>  [0,1] $

---

$f_n$ converges uniformly if $\sup|f_n - f|$ tends to zero. So using this, for (i),
\begin{align}
\sup|f_n - f|&\leq \sup |n^2 x \space e^{-nx^2}|\\
&\leq \sup |n^2 x \space e^{-x^2}|\\
&\leq \sup \space (n^2 \space e^{-nx^2})\\
&\leq n^2 \end{align} which does not tend to $0$.

So it's not uniformly convergent on $[0,1]$

Have I done this correctly?

---

For the second question, I tried using Weierstrass M-Test and it didn't work. I know that $f_n \leq 1$ but that didn't help as sum of $1$ doesn't converge.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Careful, your argument is incorrect. Showing that $|f_n-f|$ doesn't go to zero amounts to finding an positive constant $\varepsilon_0$ that bounds that difference **from below** (!!!) for infinitely many $n$, that is, there is some $\varepsilon_0$ such that  for any $N=1,2,\ldots$ one can find $n>N$ for which $|f-f_n|>\varepsilon_0$.

As a hint on the proof, note that $f_n\to 0$ pointwise. What is $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1 f_n\; ?$$

*N.B.:* It might be possible you miscopied and you meant $nxe^{-nx^2}$.

Answer (score 0):

(i)

$$f_{n}'(x)=n^{2}e^{-nx^{2}}-2n^{3}x^{2}e^{-nx^{2}}=0    \iff x=\sqrt{\frac{1}{2n}}$$

$$\sup|f_{n}(x)|= \left\vert f_{n} \left( \sqrt{\frac{1}{2n}} \right) \right\vert =\frac{n^{3/2}}{\sqrt{2}}e^{-1/2}$$

Comment: I have fixed your LaTeX, but please consider adding explanations. As it is, I assume very few people understand what you mean (I don't).

Comment: This doesn't disprove uniform convergence. It only shows that the Weierstrass M-test fails.

Comment: You're probably right but I don't see why it doesen't.

Comment: @poolpt, my bad, I am mistaken. It's good! =)